# Jquery element hover still work even if i remove the class name

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I want to remove the hover effect based on class when i click on the same element. 
this is the code:

```
<div class="myClass"> some text </div>
```

and Javascript:

```
$('.myClass').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).removeClass('myClass');
    alert('myClass is removed from the element but the hover effect still work. i dont want that i want the hover effect to work just if the element has .myClass ');
})
```

and this is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1cj2ndsa/)

Comment: Maybe use CSS `:hover` pseudo-class?

Comment: The hover effect is not based on that class – only binding the event handler is. If you want it to react dynamically to whether or not an element has that class, use event delegation instead. (See docs for `.on` for details.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class was only used to identify the element to `bind` an `event` to, namely the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events. That's why removing the class does nothing; it's the event you want to remove. This will remove those events:

```
$(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
```

Comment: Is there a way to rebind the un-binded anonymous function?

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to [Andrew Cheong's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34883565/854246), you can also use the optional selector for the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to specify elements that trigger the event like so:

```js
$(document.body).on('mouseenter', '.myClass', function () {
    $(this).css('color','red');
}).on('mouseleave', '.myClass', function () {
    $(this).css('color','black');
});

$('.myClass').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).removeClass('myClass');
    alert('myClass is removed from the element but the hover effect still work. i dont want that i want the hover effect to work just if the element has .myClass ');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myClass"> some text </div>
```

Although this operates closer to what you were thinking the `.hover()` method was doing, it may have undesirable side effects.

Answer (score 2):

The unbind is a cool option, but you can also use jQuery's [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) function, like this:

```
('.myClass').on('click', function(e) {

    $('.myClass').off('mouseleave mouseleave');

});
```

It removes the event handler in question for those `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

Updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r467fmfh/)